# Deleting blanks in excel or csv or text file

Tags: excel, csv, unix, sed, tr

I have an excel file with times that runners arrived at 9 intermediate checks. Therefore the total number of times for each participant is 9 but lots of entries between the actual times are blank spaces. How can I delete the empty spaces in each column?

[image]

I've tried converting to txt and doing the following without success because there's no longer any separation between column times:

```
tr -d ' ' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt
tr -d '[:blank:]' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt
tr -d '[:space:]' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/537956/sed-to-delete-blank-spaces

What I'm after is something like the following:

[image]

Comment: VBA could cycle through the columns and remove the blanks through SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlank).Delete or possibly sorting (the latter dependent on whether the times are always in ascending order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VBA, you can:

```
Sub deleteBlanks()
    Columns("A:Z").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Or you can use an autofilter, so you can hide blank rows in each column... then you can select area, and copy and paste as values.

Comment: If the blank cells are irregular, you might have to cycle through the columns.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. They are irregular for each column....

Comment: @HCAI, as you can see by the images, my code will work for your specific problem. It works because 'm deleting each cell at `Columns("A:Z").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp` instead of removing each row, by using `Worksheet.Columns("A:Z").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Do you know if there's a way of doing this in Unix?